# How to parse a query string in PHP?

Tags: php

Consider I have a string in PHP like this:

```
$a = "a=hello&b=welcome&c=getlost&d=sitHere";
```

I want to make an array like this:

```
$b = ["a" => "hello", "b" => "welcome", …];
```

Is it possible? I think it is possible using `explode`.

I get this data from an AJAX request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :

```
$a="a=hello&b=welcome&c=getlost&d=sitHere";

parse_str($a, $b);

print_r($b);
```

See manual: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php

Comment: `parse_str` always trips me up in that it doesn't return anything, but will put it into the second parameter you send it.

Comment: @OscarM. that (and its confusing name) is why you should wrap it. :)

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the horribly named function [`parse_str`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) in a nicer API:

```
function parse_query_string($query_string) {
    $result = [];
    parse_str($query_string, $result);
    return $result;
}
```

Then just pass it the string and it returns the associative array.

Comment: Yep The function name is horrible but it is very usable..Thanks.