How to get parse_url to work with no host PHP
I am trying to extract query parameters from a URL launch string that doesn't have a hostname and parse_url fails when trying to parse it.
Here is an example of the URL;
"vvm://?creds=ksid9ie48ijtjhfiert9e4tj&country=TEST"
If I try to get the query parameters using parse_url;
$url_components = parse_url("vvm://?creds=da992d8f1620615a55440285ac58e99a1fd29323675d55bcf4d3a31bd&country=TEST");

when I call this, $url_components returns false. If I add a domain (ie: "vvm://www.somedomain.com/?creds=da992d8f1620615a55440285ac58e99a1fd29323675d55bcf4d3a31bd&country=TEST");
I am just going to use string manipulation to handle this for now but wanted to see if there was a way to do it using parse_url.

Well, an URL without a domain part isn't an URL. You could simply replace vvm:// by vvm://a and it will work.

"If I add a domain" - looks like you forgot to finish this sentence ... ?  What happens if you add a domain as you've shown?

A search for "php parse query parameters" seems like a good place to start, and turns up many answers here already, did you see or try any of those? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5397726/parse-query-string-into-an-array, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11480763/how-can-i-get-parameters-from-a-url-string, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8469767/get-url-query-string-parameters, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4784243/how-do-i-extract-query-parameters-from-a-url-string-in-php, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24086661/how-to-parse-a-query-string-in-php ...

This question is similar to: Parse query string into an array. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You can write it this way, just replace the function parse_url with parse_str
$str = 'vvm://www.somedomain.com/?creds=da992d8f1620615a55440285ac58e99a1fd29323675d55bcf4d3a31bd&country=TEST';
parse_str(substr($str,strpos($str, '?')+1), $output);
var_dump($output);

It will output
array(2) {
["creds"]=>
string(57) "da992d8f1620615a55440285ac58e99a1fd29323675d55bcf4d3a31bd"
["country"]=>
string(4) "TEST"
}

